# Taylor series to approximate a nonlinear problem to a linear problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, rectangles

How do I convert the function $f(x,y) = xy$ (area of a rectangle) to a linear function using Taylor Series? My attempt at this is as follows (please tell me if I am right/wrong:

$L(x,y) = f(a,b) + df/dx(a,b)(x-a) + df/dy(a,b)(y-b)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's the linear Taylor polynomial at $(a,b)$, but why didn't you compute the function values?

$$\begin{align}
L(x,y)&=f(a,b)+f_x(a,b)(x-a)+f_y(a,b)(y-b)\\
&=ab+b(x-a)+a(y-b)\\
&=bx+ay-ab
\end{align}$$

**EDIT**

We have $$\begin{align}f(x,y)&=xy,\\
f_x(x,y)&=y,\\
f_x(a,b)&=b\end{align}$$
Similarly,
$$f_y(a,b)=a$$

Comment: Thanks for replying. How did you do the last two lines? I am trying to optimize this problem using the MATLAB command linprog(). That is the objective function. The constraint function is:   x + y = 50. I am not sure what to put for a and b.

Comment: I explained how to get the last two lines.  However, if you are trying to maximize $xy$ subject to $x+y=50$ you are going about it all wrong.  Just set $y=50-x$ and maximize $x(50-x)$

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I am trying to solve this on MATLAB using the linprog(f,A,B....) function. In this function, I am not sure what to put in for the objective function, "f" as this value depends on (a,b).

Comment: @NoName123 I guess I don't understand why you are trying to solve it this way, but the best linear approximation will be different at every point $(x,y)$.

Answer (score 0):

This is very correct at the first order just as you want.

So, if you need to make the problem more linear, this is the formula to be used. Since the problem is now bilinear, you could shorten the notations.